# I can't start two functions at the same time, with multiprocessing Python. Why?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I just want to start 2 functions at the same time but it doesn't work, here is it my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time as t
def print1():
    print(1)
    t.sleep(10)

def print2():
    print(1)
    t.sleep(10)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = print1)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2 = Process(target = print2)
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

I don't have any problesms on console but function doesn't start at the same time.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this post on [how to start all processes simultaneously in Python](https://pythonalgos.com/run-multiple-functions-in-parallel-in-python3/) instead of

```
    p1 = Process(target = print1)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2 = Process(target = print2)
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

do

```
    p1 = Process(target = print1)
    p2 = Process(target = print2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

then to run another function after it, you can do

```
    p1 = Process(target = print1)
    p2 = Process(target = print2)
    p3 = Process(target = print3)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.start()
    p3.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `.join()`. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join):

> If the optional argument timeout is None (the default), the method
> blocks until the process whose join() method is called terminates. If
> timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds. Note
> that the method returns None if its process terminates or if the
> method times out. Check the process’s exitcode to determine if it
> terminated.

So by calling `.join()`, you are making the process block until it terminates.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. How to start another fuction after ending multiprocessing functions in if__name___=main

Comment: @kamazz I don't understand your question. In any case, if you have another question, you should probably just open a new one (although, you should check and see if the question already exists by googling it)